# lightning-formatted-url with Target="_self" is opening in a new window in chrome from Salesforce console app

Tags: lightning-web-components, console, html5

I'm using a lightning-formatted-url with targer="_self" inside record-edit-form which has a link to a case.

upon clicking, the link is opening in a separate tab or in new window(for some users) instead of opening in the same frame in the console app. I couldn't find any settings in chrome or in SF org.

```
<lightning-formatted-url value={Url} label={Name} target="_self"
                    class="slds-p-left_xx-small">
                </lightning-formatted-url>
```

what can be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below reason for this behavior.

_self: Opens the link in the same frame as it was clicked. This is the default behavior. In Lightning Experience and Experience Builder sites, the link is opened in a new tab if it cannot be opened inside the app.

[Link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-url/documentation) to the documentation.